# vqmod set cookie to change google translate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, google-translate

I've been struggling with this for days...
MVC pattern using vQmod file.
I am trying to programmatically switch between translation languages using google translate.
code:
**vqMod file:** (also loading `js.cookie.js, googTrans.js,jquery.cookie.js`)
This vqmod modifies `header.php controller`

```
$l = $this->session->data['language'];
setcookie("googtrans", "", time()-3600); // kill cookie
setcookie("googtrans", "/en/" . $l); // set new one - does not work
setcookie("SETCOOKIE", "" . $l); // this actually worx
```

Sets first time cookie but does not rewrite the cookie afterwards

Tried changing the cookie with `jQuery.cookie.js / js.cookie.js` :
Modifing the `header.tpl` with the same vQmod file

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$.cookie('googtrans', '/en/" . $this->session->data['language'] . "');
</script>";?>
```

Before loading `googTrans.js` OR calling `//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit`

**googTrans.js**

```
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en', 
    includedLanguages: 'fr,ru', 
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, 
    multilanguagePage: true, 
    gaTrack: true, 
    gaId: 'UA-XXXXX-X'},
  'google_translate_element');
}
```

With no luck...:-(
Any ideas?? when to write the cookie? from header.php or header.tpl? why isn't php changing the cookie or for that matter neither does jQuery...
How to go about it??
If you need more info I'd be more then happy to reply.
Thanx

Comment: Check the browsers cookies, do you see 2 cookies named (googtrans) -- cookies have domain/path name too.  if you use chrome goto developer tools, resources, expand cookies -- check how to view cookies on net for other browsers

Comment: @Tasos there are 2 googtrans cookies

Comment: There you see. So make sure the Jquery cookie, and the Php cookie have the same Domain/path  -- usually for local domain is (/)  -- more info here PHP -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php  -- and here JQUERY -- https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @Tasos..I'd think you would understand...they are the same...NOT different! if they would be different don't you think I would mention is...

Comment: A strange thing I have noticed is that one cookie has a .domainname and the other (not dot) domainname as Domain...

Comment: URL http://jerusalempetshop.com/

Comment: if changing language, manually deleting the existing cookie, F5ing the page....translates to the new language...mmm...strange indeed

Comment: I also tried deleting both cookies mentioned above (domain with dot and without). I also tried defining domain on cookie creation to avoid having 2 cookies with different domains registered

Comment: php sets the cookie with the domain that it came from. to overwrite the cookie in jquery as far as i know you need to include the domain, otherwise it will create a new one

Comment: @Tasos, here is the jquery code that sets and unsets the specific cookie: <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Cookies.remove('googtrans',{path:'/', domain: 'jerusalempetshop.com'}); Cookies.remove('googtrans',{path:'/', domain: '.jerusalempetshop.com'});console.log('After remove - ' + Cookies.get('googtrans')); Cookies.set('googtrans', '/en/" . $this->session->data['language'] . "',{path:'/', domain: 'jerusalempetshop.com'});
                                console.log('AFTER SET NEW - ' + Cookies.get('googtrans'));</script>";

Comment: Try -- Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' });  -- apparently -- path: '' --- docs say Create an expiring cookie, valid to the path of the current page:

Comment: Choose either `jquery.cookie.js` or `js.cookie.js`, they are the SAME. Do not include both. The difference is that `js.cookie.js` uses `Cookies.set`, `Cookies.remove`, `Cookies.get`. `jquery.cookie.js` uses ONLY `$.cookie` and `$.removeCookie`.

See here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases

Answer (score 0):

Thanx @Tatos...you pointed me in the right direction.
The solution in my case was:

```
Cookies.remove('googtrans',{path:'', domain: 'domainNameNoDot.com'});
Cookies.remove('googtrans',{path:'', domain: '.domainNamePrecedDot.com'});
Cookies.set('googtrans', '/en/" . $this->session->data['language'] . "',{path:''});
```

Comment: Just an additional information: By default `js.cookie.js` set the path as `path: '/'`. To remove a cookie created without `path: '/'`, you need to use `path: ''` or `Cookies.defaults.path = ''` (to change the default).